# EOFError using joblib to load a trained machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, joblib

I am loading a machine learning model SVM. but the jobli library displays error.

```
Error:
/usr/lib/python3.9/pickle.py in load(self)
   1210                     raise EOFError
   1211                 assert isinstance(key, bytes_types)
-> 1212                 dispatch[key[0]](self)
   1213         except _Stop as stopinst:
   1214             return stopinst.value

KeyError: 0
```

The below code I have tried:

```
import joblib
_classifier = joblib.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/Classifers/Linear_SVC_classifier.sav")
```

I used the above same code before 1 week and it is working fine but now an error message is displays. Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: I checked these links, but my problem is not solved. I am loading saved model in google colab

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: I am working on my project and need urgent assistance please if anyone know a solution than suggest me. It's a humble request.